# Why do geysers have an almost constant period between eruptions?

Tags: earth, geophysics

I was wondering about how can geysers be so precisely predicted. For example, I was in the Yellowstone Park, and it amazed me how the eruption of the [Old Faithful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Faithful) was accurately predicted. Also, it seemed to me that the period of time between one eruption and another one has a very little variation. Isn’t it strange? What does determine the almost constant “period”? Is it like this only for the Old Faithful, or are all geysers very predictable and with an almost constant “period”?

- Note that I know very little about how geysers work in general. By reading [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/368226/354245), I thought that maybe it’s just because the magma/lava under the earth is almost always at the same temperature and thus, to reach the boiling temperature at the bottom, it takes always almost the same amount of time. Is it really just this simple or…?
- Note: I know that it isn’t really constant, as for the Old Faithful it changes from 44 minutes to 2 hours. But to me it still seems that it changes not very much, and I wouldn’t know how to describe this concept otherwise.

Comment: see https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017SPIE10169E..2KK/abstract

Comment: @annav seems that I have to pay to see it

Comment: you could go to a  university library if you want the mathematics , but the abstract is descriptive enough to answer your "why" the periodicity.